# Не отрабатывает событие 'click touchstart' на iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if ($(window).width() <= '840') {
$('#menu .menu-item a').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('#menu .menu-item a').on('click touchstart', function(){

    $(this).next('.sub-menu').toggle();
    $('#menu .sub-menu').not($(this).siblings('.sub-menu')).css('display', 'none');

    var displayValue = $(this).next('#menu .sub-menu').css('display');
        if (displayValue === 'block') {
            $(this).siblings('#menu .sub-menu').css('background-color', '#fff');
        }
```

});

```
$('#menu .sub-menu a').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu .sub-menu').css('display', 'none');
    $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');        
});
```

}

```
$('#menu-footer .menu-item a').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('#menu-footer .menu-item a').on('click touchstart', function(){
        $('#menu-footer .sub-menu').not($(this).siblings('.sub-menu')).css('display', 'none');
        $(this).siblings('#menu-footer .sub-menu').toggle();

        var displayValue = $(this).siblings('#menu-footer .sub-menu').css('display');
        if (displayValue === 'block') {
            $(this).siblings('#menu-footer .sub-menu').css({'display': 'flex', 'flex-direction': 'column'});
        }
});
```

Comment: Приведите [mcve], куски кода сами по себе ни о чём не говорят. И на андроиде проверьте

Comment: Точно не срабатывает? Подозреваю, что touchstart открывает меню, click закрывает.